# Using of colon ( : ) and comma ( , ) in a sentence

Tags: commas, colons

I have the following situation:

> Person1: Please check my website if it looks good. Here's the link: http://example.com.
>
> Person2: I checked your website`:` http://example.com`,` and it looks good.

So in the `Person2` sentence, I used `:` and `,`, is my usage of colon and comma in that case correct?

Comment: A leading comma rather than a colon is appropriate in the Person 2 sentence. The trailing comma is fine. A colon is used to set off an answer to a question set forth in the first part of the sentence; a word or phrase set off by commas is used when you are clarifying the meaning of the previous word "website". You could use ( URL ) in lieu of setting off the URL with commas, and that would also be correct.

Comment: I agree fully with @ohwilleke, for the reference. It's not the worst sin to use a colon there, but a comma is ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that you cannot, under any circumstance, "have" a situation. Always and exclusively, you will find yourself in a situation. Is the difference clear?

Before we get to the punctuation you’re asking about please note that “Please check my website if it looks good” will always be wrong. “Please check whether my website looks good” would work. “Please check my website. Does it look good?” would work. Is the difference clear?

In other circumstances - in ordinary written English - the colons and commas you ask about might be useful or even necessary.

Since the example is "webspeak", either colons or commas might be helpful but neither is needed.